# Xcode 5//iOS 6 and 7//TDD: OCUnit or XCTest

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, ocunit, xctest

I am a software engineering student enrolled in a practicum course where a small team of students works with a third-party client to solve a problem.  My team has been assigned a project that involves writing an iOS program.  None of us have ever done any iOS programming.  We are reading voraciously, but need to come up to speed as quickly as possible since the semester is only 15 weeks long.

My question is regarding testing frameworks.  Our team plans to use TDD.  Our iOS app needs to support iOS 6 and 7.  I thought I read somewhere that XCTest only supports iOS 7 and that we will need to use OCUnit in order to support iOS 6.  Is that true?  How do we write an app that supports both iOS 6 and 7?  Is it as simple as setting the deployment target to iOS 6.0 and not using any APIs that were introduced after iOS 6.0?

Comment: We haven't written any code yet.  We are still trying to determine how to set up our environment.

Comment: I would recommend reading http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380

Comment: Given your experience and time constraints, supporting iOS 6 _and_ iOS 7 might be too ambitious. The UI is quite different and this will require special consideration and thus will cost a lot of resources. In order to increase the probability that this project succeeds, concentrate on iOS 7 only, and only if there is time left, *back port* a version for iOS 6, with possibly a quite different looking UI.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, @CouchDeveloper.  If we start out writing for iOS 7 only, do our tests need to be written in OCUnit in order to make it possible for someone (us or another team at a later time) to easily port the test code to iOS 6?  YAGNI would point to us using XCTest and switch later if/when needed, but if it is possible to make the tests work for both iOS 6 and 7 by using OCUnit, then I think it would be sensible to do that.  Thanks again for the advice—it is much appreciated.

Comment: XCTest is quite similar to OCUnit. Rewriting tests written in XCTest to OCUnit isn't that much an effort. On the other hand, XCTest doesn't provide more features than OCUnit, so you can very well write the tests initially in OCUnit. ;) Both test tools aren't that great - but integration into Xcode is good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can target iOS 6 and up, but if you use XCTest, you will be able to run your tests only on iOS 7.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can use still use XCTest, but I would urge you to take a look at Kiwi (https://github.com/allending/Kiwi) in your research. It basically wraps whichever framework you choose (xctest/octest) with macros to give you a spec-style testing option. Also, it has extremely powerful mocking/stubbing support which is essential in unit testing.

Comment: Although this didn't exactly answer my question, I'm +1ing it because it was very helpful.  We tried Kiwi and couldn't get it to work, but our research led us to Cedar (https://github.com/pivotal/cedar), which is similar.